# pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError:

Tags: python

I am trying to open a program (working fine) and then on its start select the 'File' dropdown so I can save it etc and manipulate it further. However, I am getting this error:

> pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'title': 'Untitled - Notepad',
> 'backend': 'win32', 'visible_only': False}

The full error list is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\{real_name}\PycharmProjects\texture-gen\main.py", line 203, in <module>
    app = pywinauto.Application().connect(title='Untitled - Notepad')
  File "C:\Users\{real_name}\PycharmProjects\texture-gen\venv\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 997, in connect
    self.process = findwindows.find_element(**kwargs).process_id
  File "C:\Users\{real_name}\PycharmProjects\texture-gen\venv\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 87, in find_element
    raise ElementNotFoundError(kwargs)
pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'title': 'Untitled - Notepad', 'backend': 'win32', 'visible_only': False}
```

This is my code:

```
# Wait for Notepad to open
time.sleep(15)

hwnd = pyautogui.getWindowsWithTitle('Untitled - Notepad')

# Connect to the application
app = pywinauto.Application().connect(title='Untitled - Notepad')

# Get the main window of the application
window = app.window(title='Untitled - Notepad')

# Get the dropdown menu
dropdown = window.ComboBox

# Get the names of the items in the dropdown menu
items = dropdown.texts()

# Print the names of the items
print(items)
```